# Getting all survey responses from SurveyMonkey survey into csv

Tags: python, json, surveymonkey

I'm trying to use the SurveyMonkey API to collect survey responses. Ideally I would be able to collect responses and their metadata into a csv. I'm using Python 3.6

I've attempted to use the [solution outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761788/2752159), but this answer appears to be out of date. Please note that some of my survey pages do not have any questions, so I've made a slight edit. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


headers={"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % MY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           "Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%s/details" % (my_survey_id)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
survey_data = response.json()

answer_dict = {}
for page in survey_data['pages']:
    for question in page['questions']:
        # Rows, choices, other, and cols all make up the possible answers
        if question.get('answers'):
          answers = question['answers'].get('rows', [])\
            + question['answers'].get('choices', [])\
            + question['answers'].get('other', [])\
             + question['answers'].get('cols', [])

          for answer in answers:
              answer_dict[answer['id']] = answer

df = pd.DataFrame(answer_dict)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "survey-monkey-api-testing.py", line 19, in <module>
    + question['answers'].get('cols', [])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

Is there a way to get survey responses into a flattened JSON programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried converting the dictionary to a list of tuples? that would get rid of the error. Something like this: `answers.items()`. But the way you're using the dictionary doesn't make too much sense for a dictionary. You might want to implement it with a list and then add the concatenated list to each index of the answers list.

Comment: @RyanFasching, I think you're right. My issue is: I can get a JSON of how the survey is set up (questions on each page, response ids in plain english, etc), and I can get a JSON of the responses (mostly response ids). I want to know how to merge these two into a csv.

I'm assuming I should: Make a list of questions from the JSON of how the survey is set up, and then pull in the responses. Any idea how I would do that? I'm very new to lists/dicts/tuples/etc

Comment: what do you want the format of the csv file to look like? That will decide how to do things.

Comment: @RyanFasching, I'd like the output to match SurveyMonkey's web export function. An example of the format is the "All Responses" XLS export here:
https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Export-Examples

Comment: If I understand what is being asked, then you would probably need two loops to combine the two different JSON objects (like you have) but then combine the wanted results in a singular data structure (list or dictionary) and then use that to export to csv. I am still a bit unclear as to what is asking but I hope this helps.